# Compare two lists with custom functions and custom comparison

Tags: python, list, object, comparison

I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4,5]
```

and two custom functions `F1(a[i])` and `F2(b[j])`, which take elements from lists `a` and `b` return objects, say `A` and `B`. And there is a custom comparison function `diff(A,B)`, which returns `False` if the objects are the same in some sense and `True` if they are different.
I would like to compare these two lists in a pythonic way to see if the lists are the same. In other words, that all objects `A` generated from list `a` have at least one equal object `B` generated from list `b`. For example if the outcome is the following then the lists are the same:

```
(diff(F1(1),F2(4)) or diff(F1(1),F2(5)) or diff(F1(2),F2(3)) or diff(F1(3),F2(2))) is False
```

For the function `sorted` there is a `key` function. Are there any comparison functions in Python that can take a custom function in this situation?
The only solution that I see is to loop through all elements in `a` and loop through all elements in `b` to check them element by element. But then if I want to extend the functionality this would require quite some development. If there is a way to use standard Python functions this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are the results of the `F` functions hashable?

Comment: @KellyBundy In the example, 1 and 4 are not different if you are talking about the first comparison. Function diff returns False. As all four comparisons return False, the lists are not different. The functions F are not washable.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, what I am looking for is that all four comparisons in the example are False then the two lists are NOT different, in that specific case.

Comment: Thank you. I added extra brackets for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best you can get is first converting all entries of the list, and then iterate over both and check if any of `a` has a match in `b` and if that holds true for all as. So something like

```py
af = [F1(i) for i in a]
bf = [F2(i) for i in b]
is_equal = all(any(not diff(a,b) for b in bf) for a in af )
```

all stops as soon as it finds the first value that is false, any stops as soon as it finds the first value that is True.

Answer (score 1):

```
all(True if any(diff(A, B) is False for B in [F2(j) for j in b]) else False for A in [F1(i) for i in a])
```

Honestly I just typed this quickly using my Python auto-pilot but it would look something like this I guess.

Comment: This is what I call the solution with loops. I am looking for solution of type sorted(a, key=EQ(i)), where the custom function EQ takes an index from 'a' and compares to another element. But then it should be not function 'sorted' but 'difference' or 'intersect' with the custom comparison function. Otherwise, if I want to find which elements are different, it would require lots of changes. And I hope there is a standard python or bumpy or whatever function to do the job for me.

Comment: Oh true, this isn't what you were asking for. My bad. If what you're doing really needs extended functionality then building your own class(es) will probably be required, as I think it's too niche to find anything useful online